# Method extracting, generics, reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection, refactoring

First code:

```
    Bond[] bonds = null;
    try
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
        bonds = new Bond[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            bonds[i] = new Bond(json);
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Second:

```
    Announcement[] announcements = null;
    try
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
        announcements = new Announcement[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            announcements[i] = new Announcement(json);
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am thinking about extracting a method which will cover these two codes. I think the method should look more or less like this:

```
static Object[] getObjectsArray(String jsonString, Class<?> cls)
{
    Object[] objects = null;
    try
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        objects = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(cls, jsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            objects[i] = new Announcement(json); // FIXME: How to pass "json" arg to the constructor with cls.newInstance()?
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return objects;
}
```

So later instead of first code I can just call `Bond[] bonds = (Bond[]) getObjectsArray(jsonArray, Bond)`.

This is the most problematic line:

```
objects[i] = new Announcement(json); // FIXME: How to pass "json" arg to the constructor with cls.newInstance()?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to use a constructor with arguments (I assume the argument of the constructor is a `JSONObject` and that the constructor is public - if it is not, use the `getDeclaredConstructor` method):

```
Class<Announcement> cls = Announcement.class; //the second argument of your method
objects[i] = cls.getConstructor(JSONObject.class).newInstance(json);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be "Announcement.class"?

Comment: `cls = Announcement.class` and `cls.getDeclaredConstructor(JSONObject.class)` gets the constructor of Announcement that takes a JSONObject as an argument (unless I'm mixing things up?).

Comment: Oh, wait. You're right! Sorry. It would probably be best if you showed that `cls` is Announcement.class

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics to provide type safety and avoid castings, you would have to return a List though.

```
static <T> List<T> getObjectsArray(String jsonString, Class<T> cls) {
        ... 
}
```

If you have a common type (interface) between *Announcement* and *Bound* it would be nice to bound the generic type like this:

```
static <T extends YourSuperType> ...
```